# deleting node in a doubly linked list

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I wrote this code to delete a node from a linked list:

```c
void deleteNode(struct node **head, int element)
{
    if (*head == NULL)
        return;

    struct node *temp = *head;
    while (temp != NULL && temp->data != element){
        temp = temp->next;  
    }
    if (temp == NULL) {
        printf("No element in D.L.L");
    }
    else if (temp == *head) {
        *head = temp->next;
        (*head)->prev = NULL;
        free(temp);
    }
    else if (temp->next == NULL)
    {
        temp->prev->next = NULL;
        free(temp);
    }
    else {
        temp->prev->next = temp->next;
        temp->next->prev = temp->prev;
        free(temp);
    }
}
```

I call it like this:

```
deleteNode(&head, 33);
```

I dont know why the `deleteNode` function shows a core dump error when it is deleting the intermediate node? Also, it works fine for first and last nodes.

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when the list has exactly one element, and the `deleteNode` call is about to remove that element.

In that case, this piece of code executes:

```
if (temp == *head) {
    *head = temp->next;
    (*head)->prev = NULL;
    free(temp);
}
```

But as `*head` is updated to `NULL` (because `temp->next` is `NULL`), the next assignment makes an invalid reference. This `(*head)->prev = NULL` assignment should not be executed when the list has become empty.

So fix as follows:

```
    if (temp == *head) {
        *head = temp->next;
        if (*head) { // Guard against invalid dereferencing
            (*head)->prev = NULL;
        }
        free(temp);
    }
```

Side remark: it is not consistent to output a message when a node is not found in a non-empty list, but to keep silent when the list is empty. I would not output anything, and instead return a boolean value indicating whether the deletion was successful or not.